# PrimeNg V.7 FullCalendar View Crash

Tags: angular, calendar, primeng

Im building an Angular application which requires a Calendar to view events on it, Im using PrimeNG version 7 full calendar, I did install primeNG and fullCalendar using npm as follow:

> npm install fullcalendar@4.0.0-alpha.2 --save

and then just apply the basic usage of FullCalendar in the document.

```
<p-fullCalendar [events]="events"></p-fullCalendar>
```

This is the resulted view

[image]

The Calendar is not viewing as it suppose to be.

this is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "sahabeh-driving",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "github:angular/animations-builds",
    "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/http": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "^7.1.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "fullcalendar": "^4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "primeng": "^7.0.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.5",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.1.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have also to include FullCalendar's own CSS file:

```
"styles": [
   "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
   "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
   "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
   "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
   "src/styles.scss"
]
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I was missing fullcalendar.min.css file : - )